# Are questions that are "just" about Christianity on-topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics, migration

I have migrated [this question](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/1313/is-the-christian-god-just-and-or-merciful-evangelicals-if-any-please-go-first) to Christianity.SE where it has (already!) been edited into shape and has received several upvotes, which I think is a better fate than it would likely have received on here. That said, what do you think about the somewhat porous boundary between philosophy and theology, especially that the religion-oriented sites are now really up and going?

I think the energy of those sites indicates that we should probably try to migrate questions that could be more usefully answered by experts there. Ultimately I think it degrades our focus to take on too many questions are clearly within the domain of another stack, but I'm interested in hearing what others might have to say here.

Just in passing, another issue with the question was the argumentative-dismissive tone it was taking -- this was the central issue that Christianity.SE had with the question as formulated. To the point about energy, it looks like the OP has already improved the question somewhat further over there (that is, over and above the initial cleanup that a Christianity.SE mod had first performed.)

Comment: I don't object to you guys having migrated the question to Christianity.SE, but I would like to request, [please don't migrate low-quality questions to other sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82941/please-dont-migrate-low-quality-questions-to-other-sites). :)  I had to do a significant amount of clean up to make the question appropriate (i.e. non-argumentative) for _any_ SE site.

Comment: @Flimzy agreed, I will just close them in the future. I appreciate your handling of this and I apologize for the inconvenience.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this up here and for stopping over on C.SE to check back with the OP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. As a general rule, *don't migrate junk.* If a question is going to be viable ANYWHERE, do what you can to fix it before migrating. If the OP isn't interested in making a good question, shipping them off to the next community isn't going to work.
2. This one worked because the OP *does* seem to be interested in making it a good question.
3. This one worked because it specifically called for answers from a specific point of view. Even if a question was about Christianity, if the OP had come looking for Buddhist point of view on a Christian theology point, it would probably have died a horrible death.
4. Give people a heads up comment about WHY a post is being migrated. Particularly for new SE users, having their first question kicked around like a hot potato without knowing why is kind of jarring.
5. You can always check in with chat on the target site or ping some site mods in the lounge to ask about a particular question before migrating.

Comment: Thank you so much for this, these are all really great points. For my part I'll definitely be more careful about reviewing a post for quality before shipping it off somewhere, and also take care to leave detailed commentary before taking a 'big' action like that.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add to Caleb's very complete answer, I feel that questions that are 'just' about Christianity could be asked here (there's nothing necessarily non-philosophical about them).

Like with the question in question, it depends on the context, and the answers have no compunction to be contained within a Christian world-view. (the same thing could be said about non-Christian questions an answers; I welcome Michael Dorfman's explanations of Hindu and Buddhist theology, and Christian versions would be similarly very welcome too).

Answer (score 1):

Religion is distinct from philosophy and should not, unless it is qualified by additional tags, be addressed here in its non-meta form (the philosophy of religion and much of theology are obviously on-topic). Philosophy aims to study fundamental questions, whereas religion aims to study the implications of pre-set answers to fundamental questions.